# Bar plot in terminal node of tikz-qtree

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, tikz-trees, tikz-qtree

I want to draw a bar plot at the terminal nodes of a tree drawn with `tikz-qtree`.

I have tried this:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \Tree [.A 
            [.B1 {some text}
                ] 
            [.B2 {
                \begin{axis}[ybar, xtick=data, width=4cm, enlargelimits=0.2]
                    \addplot coordinates {(0,3) (1,2) (2,4)};
                \end{axis}
            }
                ]
        ]

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

In this example, the text `some text` appears in the terminal node below B1. I would like the bar plot to appear in the terminal node below B2, but it is drawn on the right side of the tree instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to TeX-SE! My groundhog friends recommend `forest` for that, where you can do such trees much easier, and if you put the plot in a `\savebox` this saves you from additional hassle.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\newsavebox\Plot
\sbox\Plot{\begin{tikzpicture}
                \begin{axis}[ybar, xtick=data, width=4cm, enlargelimits=0.2]
                    \addplot coordinates {(0,3) (1,2) (2,4)};
                \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
 [A
  [B1
   [some text]
  ]
  [B2
   [\usebox\Plot]
  ]
 ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]